# Cascading DropDown Remove Previous Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have 7 dropdown boxes in html. They will all get populated the same data. What I am trying to do is when the first dropdown is selected it would remove the selected item from the next dropdown. So, if you Have Numbers: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I in one dropdown if I select B in the first drop down then in the next dropdown it should only show A,C,D,E,F,G,H,I and so on up to 7 dropdowns. I dont know what would be the best way to approach this in JavaScript or JQuery. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
<table>
    Selected Options: <div id="123"></div>
      <tr>
         <td class="assessmentHeader" align="left"><U> Diagnosis: -  </U><br/> <!---Added code 88898 Created 7 dropdowns for Diagnosis  05/04/2012--->
           <!---<font style="visibility:hidden"><textarea name="diagnosis" rows="2" cols="5" disabled="disabled">NULL</textarea></font><br/>--->                                                                              
           Primary  : <select name="Primary" onchange="selected(this)">
           <option value=""></option>
           <cfloop query="DCheck">
           <option value="#DCheck.cDescription#" >#DCheck.cDescription#</option></cfloop>                                                      
           </select> &nbsp;&nbsp; <br/> <br/>
           Secondary: <select name="Secondary" onchange="selected(this)">
           <option value=""></option>
           <cfloop query="DCheck">
           <option value="#DCheck.cDescription#">#DCheck.cDescription#</option> </cfloop>
                                                                                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br />
           Third &nbsp;   : <select name="Third" onchange="selected(this)">
           <option value=""></option>
           <cfloop query="DCheck">
           <option value="#DCheck.cDescription#">#DCheck.cDescription#</option></cfloop>
                                                                                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br/>
            Fourth   : <select name="Fourth" onchange="selected(this)">
            <option value=""></option>
            <cfloop query="DCheck">
            <option value="#DCheck.cDescription#">#DCheck.cDescription#</option></cfloop>
                                                                                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br/>
            Fifth  &nbsp; : <select name="Fifth" onchange="selected(this)">
            <option value=""></option>
            <cfloop query="DCheck">
            <option value="#DCheck.cDescription#">#DCheck.cDescription#</option></cfloop>
                                                                                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br/>
            Sixth &nbsp; : <select name="Sixth" onchange="selected(this)">
            <option value=""></option>
            <cfloop query="DCheck">
            <option value="#DCheck.cDescription#">#DCheck.cDescription#</option></cfloop>
                                                                                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br/>
            Seventh  : <select name="Seventh" onchange="selected(this)">
            <option value=""></option>
            <cfloop query="DCheck">
            <option value="#DCheck.cDescription#">#DCheck.cDescription#</option></cfloop>
                                                                                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br />
          </td>                    
         </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Please include the HTML and jQuery thus far. If you have nothing yet start and then post with the particular issue you are having...

Comment: @iambriansreed I can post the HTML but the data for the HTML get populated from the Database so it will not help much. I dont have any JavaScript or JQuery code because I have no idea of how to even approach this. I know how to do it for 2 dropdowns but more than 2 I just get confused.

Comment: Show what you have. Dummy select options work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/AyxSE/

This works for infinite `select` tags.

jQuery

```
$('#select-group select').change(function(){

    var values = [];
    $('#select-group select').each(function(){
        if(this.value.length > 0)
            values.push(this.value);
    });

   $('#select-group select optgroup').each(function(){
        $(this).after('<option>'+          $(this).attr('label')+'</option>').remove();
    });

    $('#select-group select option').each(function(){   
        if($.inArray(this.value, values) > -1 &&
           !this.selected)                
        $(this).after('<optgroup label="'+this.value+'"></optgroup>').remove();
    });

});​
```

HTML

```
<div id="select-group">
    <select>
        <option value="">Select a ...</option>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
        <option>D</option>
        <option>E</option>
        <option>F</option>
        <option>G</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option value="">Select a ...</option>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
        <option>D</option>
        <option>E</option>
        <option>F</option>
        <option>G</option>
    </select>

</div>​
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't work well also ... specially when trying to select one then deselect it again ... wrong data will appear

Comment: @rayan.gigs Updated my answer and fiddle. :) Good catch!

Comment: Another question guys. I am running it in chrome and it works fine but when I run it in IE it does not work am I missing something?

Comment: @iambriansreed : i really like your work but i think there is small bug .... try to select option then reselect this option again (i know it's disabled) from the same <select> ...... notice the result

Comment: @rayan.gigs Updated. It won't be disabled if it is selected.

Comment: @iambriansreed I just ran the code in the jsFiddle in IE7, IE8, IE9 and Chrome. Seems like the code does not run on IE7, IE8 any ideas?

Comment: Argh, The disabled attribute is not supported in IE, prior version 8. Should I hide then?

Comment: @iambriansreed damn internet explorer causing all the problems... I tried just doing the visible = false but it does not work hmmm.

Comment: @iambriansreed .hide(); worked instead of .prop('disabled', true);

Comment: Works on IE 9 but still nothing on other browsers. The company I work for only user IE7 and IE8.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11067/discussion-between-iambriansreed-and-nick)