# Multiple level select in html

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have a select box which runs a JavaScript when the option changes.  Now I want to have multi level select, something like menus and submenus etc.

What I want is like I have Option to select Country.  As soon as mouse is cliked on country, the cities of that country are brought into the form sideways and maybe third list when city is clicked.

I have seen in this forum where Country-City-Street type select is mentioned and solved but what I want is that the value of the select should be from the last thing (from child dropdown) selected and not something like country->city->region

Also to keep that onchange thing intact.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: This is called a [cascading select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518078/cascading-dropdown-remove-previous-selected) (in [jQuery](http://www.prodiven.com/jcombo/), of course, too).

Answer (score 2):

There is jQuery plugin from Giva Labs called mcDropdown jQuery Plug-in v1.3.1, which serves similar purpose.

http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm

and another choice is: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/

Take a look at it.