# Place a dropdown list inside another dropdown list

Tags: html

Using HTML, I'm attempting to create a nested dropdown menu, but with no success so far. I placed a dropdown list inside the second item in the first dropdown list, but the inner dropdown list isn't being displayed at all, [as seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/L6n5E/):

```html
<select id="myList">
  <option></option>
  <option>Item 1</option>
    <option>Item 2 with a dropdown list inside it
        <select id="myList">
            <option></option>
            <option>Item 1</option>
            <option>Item 2</option>
        </select>
    </option>
</select>
```

Is it even possible to place one HTML dropdown list inside another HTML dropdown list?

Comment: There's a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168257/multiple-level-select-in-html

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, select option cannot contain any other html tags.

> Text with eventually escaped characters (like `&eacute;`) are only allowed inside select option.

<kbd>[See Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/option)</kbd>

Probably you want to use/create some JS plugin. The below one probably might suit your need.
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

Comment: The link above shows a jquery plugin with checkboxes inside a dropdown menu instead of dropdown menus inside a dropdown menu. Perhaps I should try to find a plugin that would allow every type of HTML element to be nested inside a dropdown menu, instead of just nesting checkboxes inside a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a nested dropdown. The standard dropdown doesn't support arbitrary html, so you have to create your own custom dropdown to achieve this.
One technique is to use a div with z-index and add expand/collapse logic to create the dropdown effect.

Comment: Have you found any working demonstrations of this type of nested dropdown, by any chance?

Comment: No I don't have one handy, but I have used this technique myself in various projects. It's a bit too much to write it up in this answer

Comment: If it's too much to write here, then you can still post it on http://pastebin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net. I still don't really understand the kind of technique you're describing - I'd need to see one or two examples in order to actually understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I found [a JQuery plugin called Droppy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/droppy/#), and it appears that it's intended to solve the problem that I've described here.

Dynamic Drive has also produced [a similar script with the same purpose](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/suckertree-menu-horizontal/#).

Comment: Do you need a dropdown menu or multilevel select control?

Comment: @PSCoder [MultiLevelSelectControl](http://www.common-controls.com/api/1_7/com/cc/framework/ui/control/MultiLevelSelectControl.html) is a Java class. I'm working with JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: i am not talking about java  MultiLevelSelectControl,  is it multi level select component or control or dropdown or menu?